# Android: Workaround for light sensor firing every time the Power button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-sensors, light

I'm working on an Android app that turns a device's screen off when the light sensor value is below a threshold value and turns the screen on again when the light sensor value rises above the threshold value. This threshold value is decided by the user through a one-time calibration. Everything works great, the screen turns on and off when it's supposed to and I've dealt with the constant fluctuations in the light sensor's values so that the screen doesn't keep turning on and off randomly.

The issue I'm facing is that when the power button is pressed, the light sensor's "onSensorChanged" event is triggered for some reason. This means that if the user presses the power button to turn the screen off, it's automatically turn back on if it's in the right lighting.

The solution I thought of was to keep a flag variable that won't allow the code in my service to execute if the power button was pressed but the issue there is that Android does not allow me to detect a power button key press from a service.

Is there another possible (perhaps a more logical) workaround to this issue?

I don't think it would be helpful to post the code but let me know if you need me to post it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tracking a flag for the power button press, why not keep a flag for when *you* turn it off? That way if it was turned off for any other reason, it won't do anything.

Edit: Another idea...

What you could do is track the last time the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` intent was fired. If the time is less than a certain threshold(0.05s?) from when your `onSensorChanged` is called, you can just disregard(or at least not turn it back *on*).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd thought of this but would only use it as a last resort, for the sake of the user. People have a habit of pressing the power button and then sticking their phones in their pocket(Which will turn the screen off anyways, I know, but users tend to nitpick). When they take it back out though, the screen should turn back on. This works if I use the proximity sensor because the power button does not trigger its onSensorChanged. As far as I can tell, this button is the only thing (apart from light) that triggers the light sensor, so I only need to worry about this one button.

Comment: I see what you mean. Out of curiosity, why aren't you using the proximity sensor, then? Maybe the light sensor should just be a fallback for devices without prox sensors?

Comment: The default sensor for my app is the proximity sensor. Indeed, the light sensor is just a fallback (most tablets don't have a proximity sensor), and a nice extra feature (since some people report lower battery usage while using the light sensor). The thing is, even though it is a fallback, I want it to work just as well (and in the same manner) as the proximity sensor and to my surprise, it worked beautifully! Never would have guessed it by how terrible Auto-brightness is on my Note, but oh, the joy of watching it work its magic in my app...except for this rather pesky and unexpected issue.

Comment: Ah, so you mean whenever onSensorChanged is called, check to see whether the screen was just turned off (0.05s ago for example), in which case, don't turn it back on (disregard it)? I guess I'll have to register a BroadcastReceiver and track the system time whenever the Intent is fired. Hopefully Android makes my life easier and fires off that Intent before calling onSensorChanged, but other than that it seems like a plausible solution. I'll try it out as soon as I can! Thanks!